# SQLWorkbench connection to Redshift drops within seconds

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I've been using SQLWorkbench to access a redshift db. I always connect successfully and then am able to either run some sql or use the db explorer utility. But if I try to run the same or different code within a few seconds, the connection has usually dropped and I have to re-establish the connection. I haven't really tried to use the Connect Script boxes on the connection page because I don't understand the syntax. Any suggestions for establishing a connection that doesn't timeout so quickly?